# JQuery .hover() functions external

Tags: jquery

I run into a little problem today. I've a divbox. This divbox should expand if I hover it and should collapse if I leave it.

so I write two functions:

1. function expand(){....};
2. function collapse(){....};

and then i tried to do the hover effect as following:

```
$('.divboxes').hover(expand(), collapse());
```

I thought this will work...but...not.

several times I used it like:

```
$('.divboxes').hover(function(){...},function(){...});
```

and it worked...so can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? I want the functions external!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from the function names because this is attaching the output of the expand/collapse functions to the events.

```
$('.divboxes').hover(expand, collapse);
```

Comment: xD gr8 one, I realy dont realize this! Thx you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.divboxes').hover(expand, collapse);
```

You just have to pass the reference to the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the name of the function.

```
$('.divboxes').hover(expand, collapse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use it like this:

```
$('.divboxes').hover(expand, collapse);
```